# jQuery Tablesorter plugin doesn't work with rowspan in table body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Does this plugin simply not work with columns which have rowspan?

Here is an example: http://www.dnsdebug.com/sortable-rowspan.html

I presume I'm going to have to delve into the plugin to make it work?

Comment: Have you solved this problem, if yes, please provide some solution or idea, I am also having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin does not support it because it does not known how you want to handle a "rowspaned" cell. Does it gives its value to all of the rows it uses ? Or only the first ?

Even if it is clear in your mind, a computer cannot guess. I recommend to use some tabs without rowspans because it will be easier to program for you and easier to read and understand for the user.

Comment: Yes, thanks- I understand why it doesn't know which one to sort on, but I want to know if there is a solution to this. Ideally I want the whole set of rows within that colspan to be treated as one and kept in the same order